# How to delete detached proxies in NHibernate

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

When we try to delete detached proxies nhibernate throws a mapping exception:

```
NHibernate.MappingException: No persister for: SomeClassProxy
   bei NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl.GetEntityPersister(String entityName)
   bei NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.GetEntityPersister(String entityName, Object obj)
   bei NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultDeleteEventListener.OnDelete(DeleteEvent event, ISet transientEntities)
   bei NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.FireDelete(DeleteEvent event)
   bei NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Delete(Object obj)
   ...
```

The objects are detached because they are primary loaded to show them to the user. Therefore the session is closed after loading.
We already tried reattaching them using `Session.Lock` but that fails with the same exception.

Typically the cause of this type of exception seems to be a wrong implemented interceptor. But we do not use any interceptors...

What is the correct way to delete detached proxies?
Why does nhibernate not recognize that these objects are proxies and select the persister for the base type?

We are using NHibernate 3.3.1.

Comment: The typical cause of this exception is when you try to use a class that is not mapped with NHibernate.

Comment: You probably shouldn't serialize proxies. It doesn't make sense to combine lazy loading with serializing anyway. In our project, we stopped serializing NH entities and mapped them to DTOs. Despite of the additional effort to implement the mapping and the DTOs, it is still much easier to handle.

Comment: @StefanSteinegger: We do not serialize proxies. The proxy type is generated by NHIbernate for our entity because it has a property configured to be loaded lazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly why you got into this problem. There is probably a way to avoid it.

However, there is a workaround.

```
var attachedEntity = session.Get<MyType>(mayBeProxy.Id);
session.Delete(attachedEntity);
```

It you want to implement it more generic (because you probably don't know the Type at compile time), you can implement it like this. (Something to put into a helper method.)

```
// find actual type and unproxy the entity
object unproxiedEntity = mayBeProxy;
INHibernateProxy proxy = mayBeProxy as INHibernateProxy;
if (proxy != null)
{
    unproxiedEntity = proxy.HibernateLazyInitializer.GetImplementation();
}
var type = unproxiedEntity.GetType()
```

You may be able to delete the unproxied entity directly

```
session.Delete(unproxiedEntity);
```

If this failes, because the unproxied entity is not in the session, get its ID by accessing the meta data and load it from the session.

```
// get the ID of the entity
var metaData = session.SessionFactory.GetClassMetadata(type);
var id = metaData.GetIdentifier(unproxiedEntity);

// load the entity and delete it
var attachedEntity = session.Get(type, id);
session.Delete(attachedEntity);
```